# How do I get the version number of a snap package?

Tags: snap, versions, version-control

If I want to install VLC using apt, I can run

```
apt-cache show vlc | grep -i version
Version: 2.2.4-14ubuntu2
```

This will tell me the version that apt will pull in. Snap currently has VLC 3.x in it's repository. How do I see this though without pulling it down, and installing it?

Comment: run `snap version`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`snap info` is in theory what you want. However, it's up to the developer to tell the store what version they've uploaded. The vlc developers haven't done this:-

```
alan@gort:~$ snap info vlc
name:      vlc
summary:   "The ultimate media player"
publisher: videolan
contact:   https://www.videolan.org/support/
description: |
  VLC is the VideoLAN project's media player. It plays MPEG, MPEG-2, MPEG-4,
  DivX, MOV, WMV, QuickTime, WebM, FLAC, MP3, Ogg/Vorbis files, DVDs, VCDs,
  podcasts, and multimedia streams from various network sources.

channels:              
  stable:    daily (4) 120MB -
  candidate: daily (4) 120MB -
  beta:      daily (4) 120MB -
  edge:      daily (4) 120MB -
```

However with other snaps the developer has, e.g:-

```
alan@gort:~$ snap info atom
name:      atom
summary:   "A hackable text editor for the 21st Century."
publisher: flexiondotorg
contact:   snappy-canonical-storeaccount@canonical.com
description: |
  Atom is a free and open source text editor that is modern,
  approachable, and hackable to the core.

commands:
  - atom
tracking:    edge
installed:   1.16.0 (2) 150MB classic
refreshed:   2017-04-21 16:35:56 +0100 BST
channels:               
  stable:    1.16.0 (2) 150MB classic
  candidate: 1.16.0 (2) 150MB classic
  beta:      1.16.0 (2) 150MB classic
  edge:      1.16.0 (2) 150MB classic
```

I would consider this a bug in the upstream package and the developer should resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

How about `snap list`:

> list all packages and grep the version displayed there

```sh
$snap list
Name     Version   Rev    Tracking       Publisher     Notes
core18   20210722  2128   latest/stable  canonical✓    base
snapd    2.51.4    12883  latest/stable  canonical✓    snapd
```

Use `grep` for a specific package :

`snap list | grep vlc`